# Use np.genfromtxt to read data of different dtypes in csv file

Tags: python, numpy, csv, genfromtxt

I am trying to read a csv file of that looks like:

```
label,value
first,1.234e-01
second,5.678e-02
three,9.876e-03
...
```

etc

Where the first column contains strings and the second column contains floats.

From the online documentation of np.genfromtxt I thought that the line

```
file_data = np.genfromtxt(filepath, dtype=[('label','<U'),('value','<f4')], delimiter=',', skip_header=1)
```

would specify the dtype of each column which would allow it to be read appropriately but when I try to print file_data I get something that looks like

```
[('', 1.234e-01) ('', 5.678e-02) ('', 9.876e-03) ...]
```

when I was expecting

```
[('first', 1.234e-01) ('second', 5.678e-02) ('third', 9.876e-03) ...]
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to specify an approximate expected number of unicode chars in `dtype` (like `<U10`):

```
from io import StringIO

data = '''label,value
first,1.234e-01
second,5.678e-02
three,9.876e-03'''

file_data = np.genfromtxt(StringIO(data), dtype=[('label','<U15'),('value','<f4')], delimiter=',', skip_header=1)
print(file_data)
```

---

```
[('first', 0.1234  ) ('second', 0.05678 ) ('three', 0.009876)]
```